# How may I transfer my media from a Maxtor OneTouch drive to WHS?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-home-server, external-hard-drive, portable-harddrive

I have a great deal of music on my OneTouch, which I would like to stream from my new HP Mediasmart EX490 to my XBox 360. Using the Windows Home Server console does not seem to be any help? I may either set the OneTouch up as a drive on one of the computers I back up, or I may connect it to the EX 490 as a backup for the server. The MP3's are organized in folders by artist name (That's how Zune does it apparently). How may I simply copy these files, and to where, to my WHS?

Answer (score 1):

Having used Windows Home Server, but not one with HP's extra features, I'd try the following, on one of the PCs that you back up:

1. Attach the One Touch drive, and browse to your music collection
2. View the Shared Folders on your server, and open the Music folder
3. Copy the files across.

Is that the sort of thing you had in mind?

Having said all that, I've read that the EX490 has "HP media collector" - see [this PC Pro review](http://www.pcpro.co.uk/reviews/desktops/352870/hp-mediasmart-server-ex490) - so presumably that should further simplify things for you.

Comment: This doesn't work automatically. Instead it assumes the drive is a new drive on the client and wants to add said drive to the client's drives to be backed up. This drive is my previous back drive for all my machines. so that would be a bit redundant.

Comment: Interesting. I don't that prompt on my system, when connecting a drive to a client.

Answer (score 0):

Having never used Windows Home Server myself (I'm a linux server fan) I'll still take a stab.  Have you tried just connecting the drive and then sharing that drive.  I believe that USB 2.0 can handle the speed of streaming the music across the network.

Comment: When I do this WHS assumes its to backup the home server, and insists that I wipe the drive first. This is not what I want of course.

Comment: According to [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/9686/add-an-external-hard-drive-to-your-windows-home-server/) How-to-Geek guide it's a pretty simple thing to add an external hard drive and use it for storage and NOT backup.